# Image Rotating in sharepoint using HTML

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I have used this piece of code in share point content editor web-part to rotate the image but it is not working in share-point though it works here.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/verashn/6rRnd/5/)

Code sample

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100/" data-rotate="90">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/110/110/" data-rotate="45">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/120/120/">

<!-- or use CSS -->
<img src="http://placekitten.com/130/130/" class="rotate90">
```

Edit:  I have placed the above code in a text file and then uploaded it into my share-point. I created a new page and added a content editor web-part add located the text file to display the image file with rotating effects.

Comment: Please add more info explaining how it's currently displayed in your project and perhaps include some markup here. In the case of jquery maybe your script is not properly included or runs too early.

Comment: Could you add the full code of your text file or if you are adding the JS and CSS code in separate files please explain how are you referencing them in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the code from [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/verashn/6rRnd/5/) into a Content Editor Web Part and it works quite well.

Here is the complete code that I inserted into a CEWP (**updated according to comments**):

```
<!-- HTML part -->
<img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100/" data-rotate="90" class="myClass">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/110/110/" data-rotate="45" class="myClass">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/120/120/">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/130/130/" class="rotate90 myClass">

<!-- JQuery reference -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- JS part -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* waits until all page elements are loaded */
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('img.myClass').each(function() {
            var deg = $(this).data('rotate') || 0;
            var rotate = 'rotate(' + $(this).data('rotate') + 'deg)';
            $(this).css({ 
                '-webkit-transform': rotate,
                '-moz-transform': rotate,
                '-o-transform': rotate,
                '-ms-transform': rotate,
                'transform': rotate 
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- CSS part -->
<style type="text/css">
    img.myClass {
        margin: 20px;
        transition: all 400ms; /* duration is 400 miliseconds */
        transition-delay: 5s; /* starts after 5 seconds */
    }

    /* or use CSS */
    .rotate90 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
</style>
```

A few things to take in count:

- I added all the code in the same CEWP.
- I added a JQuery reference which was not included in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/verashn/6rRnd/5/) because that page was loading it on the background, however SharePoint doesn't do that by default, unless you add it to your master page.
- I added the class "myClass" to the img elements because the CSS style was too general and was affecting other img elements of the page, regardless they were outside the CEWP.

Update:

- Added $(window).load to run javascript code after all page elements are loaded, thus ensuring the required behavior.
- Added transition-delay so the transition can start after a specefic amount of secods.

Comment: After adding this code, i can see the image but it is not rotating. sometimes it works. Any thoughts?. Also is there any time limit we can fix here that 30 seconds after loading, image should start rotating.Something like this.

Comment: I solved the loading issue by using $(window).load to ensure the execution of code after the loading of all page elements. Also I added the CSS property transition-delay so you can specify when to start the transition.